# Search for word in dictionary and return row

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a search function for a program that displays company info from a CSV file. I'm using csv.DictReader to get the contents of the file into a dictionary and I appened the dictionaries into an array. Right now I'm having trouble with searching for a word in the dictionary (or the array) and displaying the row that word is in. Here is a small example of the CSV file.

```
CustomerID,CompanyName,ContactName,ContactTitle,Address,City,Region,PostalCode,Country,Phone,Fax
ALFKI,Alfreds Futterkiste,Maria Anders,Sales Representative,Obere Str. 57,Berlin,NULL,12209,Germany,030-0074321,030-0076545
AROUT,Around the Horn,Thomas Hardy,Sales Representative,120 Hanover Sq.,London,NULL,WA1 1DP,UK,(171) 555-7788,(171) 555-6750
```

The code I have right now is the user input which is:

```
def search_company(data):
    word = input("Search for a company name: ")
```

How would I make it so I get these results?

```
Search for a company name: Around the Horn

AROUT,Around the Horn,Thomas Hardy,Sales Representative,120 Hanover Sq.,London,NULL,WA1 1DP,UK,(171) 555-7788,(171) 555-6750
```

I tried doing this, but it seems this only works if you're just reading from a list and not a dictionary.

```
for i, row in enumerate(data):
            for j, column in enumerate(row):
                if word in column:
                    print(row)
```

Comment: Reading that file should be a good first step. I don't see anything in your code that attempts to do that, nor search in it. All you got now is a useless prompt.

Comment: Reinventing of the wheel. Use database/sql engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple solution:

```
import csv 

word = input("Search for a company name: ")

with open(csv_path) as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in csvreader:
        if row[1] == word:
            print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was so focused on iterating over the data I didn't think about just reading it from the actual file.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import csv
def search_company(data):
    word = input("Search for a company name: ")
    f=open(data)
    my_reader=csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=",")
    for row in my_reader:
        for entry in row:
            if row[entry]==word:
                print(row)
search_company("example.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you! Again, I was focused on iterating over the data, I didn't think about reading it from the actual file.